# TLS on LDAP with Nginx as the reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ldap, openldap, starttls

I've setup the LDAP server to run on:

`SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap://192.168.56.104:3389/"`.

I can check that using the `ps aux`:

```sh
root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# ps aux | grep slapd
openldap    8931  0.0  0.2 1339368 8852 ?        Ssl  20:41   0:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap://192.168.56.104:3389/ -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
root       10963  0.0  0.0   9124   840 pts/1    S+   21:15   0:00 grep --color=auto slapd
```

and then I configured Nginx as a reverse proxy over the OpenLDAP server along with TLS. Here's the configuration:

```sh
root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# cat /etc/nginx/conf.stream.d/ldap.conf
stream {

    upstream backend {
        server 192.168.56.104:3389;
   }

    server {
        listen     192.168.56.104:3388 ssl;
        proxy_pass backend;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/conf.stream.d/ldap-certs/192.168.56.104.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/conf.stream.d/ldap-certs/192.168.56.104-key.pem;
    }
}
```

Nginx works as well:

```sh
root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# ps aux | grep nginx
root       10713  0.0  0.0  56736  1628 ?        Ss   20:57   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   10714  0.0  0.2  57436  7176 ?        S    20:57   0:00 nginx: worker process
root       10997  0.0  0.0   8992   912 pts/1    S+   21:17   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx

root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# netstat -antp | grep LISTEN
# redundant info removed
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.104:3388     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10713/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 192.168.56.104:3389     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8931/slapd
```

And then I can search using `ldapsearch` too:

- without -Z flag:

```sh
root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://192.168.56.104:3388 -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=code,dc=com" -W -b "dc=code,dc=com"  '(memberuid=alice)'
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=code,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (memberuid=alice)
# requesting: ALL
#

# codeadmin, Groups, code.com
dn: cn=codeadmin,ou=Groups,dc=code,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: codedmin
gidNumber: 5001
memberUid: alice

# search result
search: 3
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

- with -Z flag:

```sh
root@ldap-client:/etc/nginx# ldapsearch -x -Z  -H ldaps://192.168.56.104:3388 -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=code,dc=com" -W -b "dc=code,dc=com"  '(memberuid=alice)'
ldap_start_tls: Protocol error (2)
        additional info: unsupported extended operation
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=code,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (memberuid=alice)
# requesting: ALL
#

# codeadmin, Groups, code.com
dn: cn=codeadmin,ou=Groups,dc=code,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: codeadmin
gidNumber: 5001
memberUid: alice

# search result
search: 3
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

I'm not sure why it works because I did not pass the CA CERT to any of the `ldapsearch` execution. Is this insecure TLS in which the client is not verifying the CA?

And, what is the reason behind the error message that appeared with the -Z flag?

```sh
ldap_start_tls: Protocol error (2)
        additional info: unsupported extended operation
```

While searching the web, I see that all the responses configure the OpenLDAP server with TLS certs itself and Nginx does not come into play so I did not get any help there.

Thanks!